# How to limit ZBar QR code reader to only detect QR codes?

Tags: android, zbar

I have implemented [ZBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/) reader in my android application and are only using it to read QR codes. How can I limit ZBar to only detect QR codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer randomly an another ZBar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816726/issue-with-zbar-qr-code-scanner-on-sony-phone) answer by [@Sydwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344050/sydwell)

The following code solves the problem:

```
scanner = new ImageScanner();
// Only enable the codes your app requires
scanner.setConfig(Symbol.QRCODE, Config.ENABLE, 1);
```